# Blocking queue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I need to create a blocking queue in Javascript. There are `pop()` and `shift()` methods in [Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop), but the description says:

> **Return value:** The last element from the array; *`undefined` if the array is empty.*

I need a method which does **not** return `undefined`, but waits until there is some element to return.

The purpose is, that my code is driven by multiple asynchronous operations which pushes elements to the queue and I need to process them.

Comment: how's that different from an event stream?

Comment: @YuriBlanc why do you want to do complex stuff?

Comment: it's not complex stuff.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase. Why do you want to use the wrong solution for such a problem?

Comment: Ok use an event, with a timeout to simulate threads.

Comment: Javascript is single-threaded so this type of pattern doesn't make sense. If the thread is blocked then nothing else runs.

Comment: @ccarton it seems you don't understand the difference between parallelism and concurrency. Looks at how NodeJS does async for an exemple of what the OP wants

Comment: @Ven Ofcourse I understand the difference. I have no doubt that there is a way to solve his problem with concurrent techniques, such as a promise, but that is not what he asked. I'm trying to explain why the very specific question he is asking can't work in javascript. I'm not trying to solve his larger problem, which he didn't actually ask about.

Comment: Okay guys, I know all these fancy stuff like Promises and Observables, so please feel free to answer in a more idiomatic approach. I will be happy to reprogram my brain, if I think of the problem in a bad way.

Comment: @ccarton a "blocking queue" isn't necessarily the same as "a queue blocking the event loop".

Comment: @tomasbedrich take a look at [`async.queue()`](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.queue).

Answer (score 3):

Simple implementation with push shift

```
function Queue() {
  this.listeners = [];
  this.queue = [];
}

Queue.prototype = {
  shift: function(cb) {
    this.queue.length > 0 ? cb(this.queue.shift()) : this.listeners.push(cb);
  },
  push: function(value) {
    if (this.listeners.length > 0) {
      this.listeners.shift()(value);
      return;
    }

    this.queue.push(value);
  }
}


var queue = new Queue();

// 'some value'
queue.shift(function(value) { console.log(value); });

setTimeout(function() { 
  queue.push('some value'); 
  queue.push('another value');

  // 'another value'
  queue.shift(function(value){ console.log(value); });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: So basically this is a buffer, right? You keep track of "pre-requested" items in `this.listeners` and "pushed, not requested yet" items in `this.queue`.

Comment: something like that. i guess there are many libraries that do things like this better than my code, try to find something. This code is just for example

Comment: This should really use `push()` and `shift()` so that it acts like a queue as its name implies rather than a stack. The listeners as well.

Comment: I think the terms `push` and `shift` should be `add` and `poll` respectively